# Ler string explicitamente como um Array - PHP

Tags: php, array

Seguinte eu preciso transformar a string abaixo em um vetor multidimensional:

```
 $tesste = "[ ['Faturamento', 32000, '2017-05-23',[ 'Tes-OBI' => 'TESTE']],['Faturamento', 50000, '2017-05-24',[ 'Tes-OBI' => 'TESTE']]]";
```

Existe alguma lógica ou função que posso utilizar para que a variável $tesste se torno um array respeitando a dimensões das chaves []

reparem que na parte 'TES-OBI' é um array dentro de outro.

Comment: não teria como retornar um json ao invés da estrutura nesse formato? php trabalha muito melhor com estruturas do tipo json